# A hypothetical question about a fan/blade spinning near the speed of light in a vacuum

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

This question I find difficult to propose in a way that doesn't sound like it is a stupid question, but I will give it a try.

Suppose I place a fan suspended above the ground in a vacuum. The fan is oriented such that relative to my frame of reference spinning at 99.99% C.

[image: Terrible Drawing of Setup]

If I were to release that fan from rest, and let it fall under the influence of Earth's gravity, (still in the vacuum).

Would it fall relative to my frame of reference with an acceleration $g$? or will it fall slower since I observe the blade having "time move slower for it" than for me? Or something else entirely.

I know this question is slightly dumb but I have been super curious about it and can't find anything on this type of question.

Comment: Note that things spinning faster than the speed of sound (in that material) tend to shatter.

Answer (score 4):

It will fall with the regular gravitational acceleration, just like a hammer and a feather fall with the same rate. Instead of spinning blades you can also take a box filled with gas and heat it up until the atoms bounce around with almost the speed of light.

It will become heavier due to the energy you put in (with a hot box where the atoms bounce in all possible directions the mass increase will equal E/c², while on a spinning disc the metric would be more complicated due to the induced frame dragging and since we only have axial, not spherical symmetry, but you get the point), but light and heavy objects fall with the same acceleration in a vacuum.

The proper time of an observer sitting on the edge of the blade will be less though due to his kinematic time dilation, but in terms of the resting oberver's time the spinning fan takes as long to land on the floor as the nonspinning one. If both fans are released simultaneously, they also land on the floor simultaneously.

Comment: So, the problem that I see with this answer is that when the center of gravity of the fan gets up to roughly $0.01 \sqrt(2) c$ the tips will appear to be moving at the speed of light, and if it's falling faster than that then they will be exceeding the speed of light.

So there's some relativistic (apparent) weirdness that has to go on to resolve the paradox.

Comment: @TimWescott - it won't exceed c due to the [relativistic velocity addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula). That's relativity 101, see the photon in [Einstein's elevator](https://bit.ly/40wpM2R). Instead of a spinning fan you can also make a loop out of a fiber optics cable, then send a photon into a circular path inside of it and let that fall, that's the same story: the light inside of the moving fiber optics cable will always move with c in every local frame, just like the photon in [Einstein's light clock](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Light-clock.png).

Comment: @Yukterez We use normal velocity addition to add the vertical and the horizontal velocities. Horizontal velocity decreases as vertical velocity increases. It's the time dilation.

Answer (score -2):

When we spun up the fan by applying a torque on it, we noticed that the rotational inertia of the fan was approximately proportional to the total energy of the fan squared.

Then we speculated that if we added kinetic energy to the fan without applying torque on it, then the rotational inertia of the fan would increase, and in order to the law of conservation of angular momentum to not be violated, the fan should slow down.

And lo and behold, when we added kinetic energy to the fan by pushing it, it slowed down.

So does the above answer your question, although there was no gravity? Or do you want a general relativist treatment of a dropped spinning fan?